# How to use a text file as a database?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a large text file that will be use as an English dictionary database. (A real dictionary)

The user will type a word in a Search Bar and the app will return all the line of the text file that contains this word.

*-Each line explains the meaning of one word

-Some words are located on more than one line in my text file*

**Here is my logic**:

First I am looking for the word in **self.entriesFromFile** (which is one String of my Text File):

```
var range:NSRange? = self.entriesFromFile!.rangeOfString(searchText)
```

Then I find the **Substring**:

```
var substring:NSString = self.entriesFromFile!.substringToIndex(range!.location)
```

I split the **Substring** into lines

```
var substringArray:NSArray = substring.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Like this **substringArray.count** will return the current line where searchText has been found. I need the line number to identify the word in the dictionary for further functions.

I used this logic because I need it to be fast for the user, the text file contains more than 60,000 lines.

This works fine but it only return the first entry that have been found.

**Could you help me find how to return all the lines number containing the searched word?**

**Thank you for your precious help**

Comment: why use a text file? why not an actual database, like sqlite?

Comment: Hi Mark. We have the file already like this. For now I have to use a text file but for sure in the future we will have to migrate.

Comment: Don’t load a large text file into memory and enumerate through it doing string comparisons - performance will be horrible. Use SearchKit http://nshipster.com/search-kit/ or SQLite FTS http://newyankeecodeshop.tumblr.com/post/97617794988/full-text-search-on-ios-with-fmdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enumerate the lines** and search each of them:

```
var lines: [String] = []
var lineNumber = 1; // or start with 0
self.entriesFromFile.enumerateLinesUsingBlock { line, stop in
    if line.rangeOfString(searchedText) != nil {
        lines.append(line) // or store the lineNumbers
    }
    lineNumber++
}
```

I wrote the code directly here, it may need changes to compile :P

Answer (score 2):

```
// I assume that searchText already has all file content
var lines = searchText.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
var lineNumber = 0
for line in lines {
  // It will fire 60.000 times
  if string.rangeOfString("Some string you are searching for") != nil {
    linesNumbers.append(lineNumber)

  }
  lineNumber++
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working.The thing is it's very slow because my file is very long.

Comment: You are welcome, please mark it as correct/up vote:)